# Rewriting a subdomain to root/subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have the following location: `localhost/dir1/ex.html`

I'm trying to achieve a situation where `dir1.localhost/ex.html` maps to that first url. The following .htaccess rule works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =dir1.localhost
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/dir1/$1 [L]
```

However, this is not what I am looking for as it quite obviously redirects. I want to keep the url the same (`dir1.localhost`).

How would one go about doing this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your subdomain to point to the folder internally ,Remove the hostname from your rule's destination :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =dir1.localhost
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir1/$1 [L]`
```

Comment: Sadly this gives me a 500 error (Apache error log referring to: `AH00124 - Request exceeded limit of 10 internal redirects`). I've tried this both with localhost and some gibberish domain (including subdomain) that I temporarily set up in my hosts file. Would this be due to misconfiguration? My previous .htaccess rules had functioned just fine up until now (and yes, I removed those while testing).

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks a lot Starkeen!